# meaning of the values of sent_status on msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I am sending emails from SQL Server, and need to map the values of the `sent_status` column on the `msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems` table to something more descriptive.

So far I have identified two values:

- 1 = 'Sent'
- 2 = 'Failed'

Are there any more possible values, and if so what do they represent?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
sent_status, --0 new, not sent, 1 sent, 2 failure or 3 retry.
```

Comment: What is the source of this information? I can't find it in the official documentation.

Answer (score 10):

On [the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175056%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) for the related `msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems` table, the description for `sent_status` says:

> The status of the mail. Possible values are:
>
> sent - The mail was sent.
>
> unsent - Database mail is still attempting to send the message.
>
> retrying - Database Mail failed to send the message but is
>   attempting to send it again.
>
> failed - Database mail was unable to send the message.

Connecting the two views together as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mi.sent_status, ai.sent_status 
FROM 
    msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems ai
     FULL OUTER JOIN 
    msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems mi ON 
        ai.mailitem_id = mi.mailitem_id
```

Will yield a relationship, which can be expressed with the following `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT 
    CASE sent_status
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Unsent'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Sent'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Retrying'
        END AS sent_status_desc
FROM msdb..sysmail_mailitems
```